# About Weil's proof of "Weil conjectures for curves and abelian varieties"

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, weil-conjectures

I know that the Weil's proof of the *Weil conjectures for curves and abelian varieties* is made under the lenguage of his "Foundation of algebraic geometry", however in "Polarizations and Grothendieck's Standard conjectures" Milne says:

> In examining Weil’s proofs (Weil 1948) of the Riemann hypothesis
>   for curves and abelian varieties over finite fields, Grothendieck was led to state two
>   “standard” conjectures (Grothendieck 1969), which imply the Riemann hypothesis
>   for all smooth projective varieties over a finite field, essentially by Weil’s original argument.

Is there a proof of the *Weil conjectures for curves and abelian varieties* in modern (mathematical)language such that follows the Weil's original argument?

Comment: See Milne's 1986 article on Abelian Varieties, 19.1.

Answer (score 4):

http://jmilne.org/math/xnotes/pRH.html might be of interest to you (proof of the Riemann Hypothesis for curves on p. 10 and for Abelian varieties on p. 22) and http://jmilne.org/math/articles/1986b.pdf (proof of the Riemann Hypothesis for Abelian varieties).

Answer (score 3):

Kleiman's paper "Algebraic Cycles and the Weil Conjectures", in the book "Dix Exposes Sur La Cohomologie des Schemas" is, I think, what you're looking for.